# Regular expression to update RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2013

I have a WPF application in which I am using following

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomeProperty);
```

I just found that it would increase the performance if we replace the above expression by following

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => "SomeProperty");
```

I am using `RaisePropertyChanged` at thousands of places, can anybody help me writing the regular expression to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

regex to find

```
this\.RaisePropertyChanged\(\(\) => this\.(?<prop>\w+)\);
```

to replace

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => "${prop}");
```

clean simple and easy to understand

`\w` look for word characters so much easier to identify the variable or property name.

also marked match with the name `prop` to make it easier to use while replacing, it will be more useful when you have multiple matching groups.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In the `Find what` text box, place the following: `this\.RaisePropertyChanged\(\(\) => this\.(.+?)\);`.

In the `Replace with` text box, place this: `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => "$1");`.

The regular expression above will look for this text: `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.<name>` and replace it with `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => "<name>");`

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, you can replace this using the built-in regular expressions:

```
this\.RaisePropertyChanged\(\(\) => this.(.*)\);
```

With this:

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => "$1");
```